# Redirecting on if condition in yii2

Tags: yii2

On clicking of prict button in actioncolumn, I want to pass the data to page _printinvoice. This part is working fine. Now, I want to an if statement just before passing to the view page. If console is GM I want to pass to _printinvoicegm and if console is SM. I want to pass to _printinvoicesm. I've tried the following code in controller action.

```
public function actionPrintinvoice($id) {

        $model = Bills::find()->where(['bills_ebillid' => $id])->one();
        $searchModel  = new BillsSearch();
        $searchModel->console = $consoleid;
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $consoleid);
        //$data         = Sellsg::findOne($id);
        $searchModel1 = new ProductsalesSearch();
        $searchModel1->productsales_ebillid = $id;
        $dataProvider1 = $searchModel1->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        // $modelOffer  = Offers::find()->orderBy('of_id')->limit(1)->one();
        // $searchModel2 = new OffersSearch();       
        // $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        if($consoleid == 'GM1' || $consoleid == 'GM2'){
            $content = $this->renderPartial('_printinvoicegm', [
            'model' => $model,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel'  => $searchModel,

            'searchModel1' => $searchModel1,
            'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,

            // 'modelOffer' => $modelOffer,
            //'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,          
            //'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
            ]);
        $footer = "<table name='footer' width=\"1000\">
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\"><u>GM</u></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\">9:00am to 9:00pm</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\">Friday Morning Closed</td>             
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"right\">Prop:      M.Sinha</td>
           </tr>
         </table>";
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
            'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            //'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            // any css to be embedded if required
            'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
             // set mPDF properties on the fly
            'options' => ['title' => 'Print Invoice'],
            //'options' => ['defaultfooterline' => 0,],
             // call mPDF methods on the fly
            'methods' => [
                //'SetHeader'=>['Amit Optical'], 
                'SetFooter'=>[$footer],
            ],
            'content' => $content,

        ]);

        }elseif($consoleid == 'SM1' || $consoleid == 'SM2'){
            $content = $this->renderPartial('_printinvoicegm', [
            'model' => $model,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel'  => $searchModel,

            'searchModel1' => $searchModel1,
            'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,

            // 'modelOffer' => $modelOffer,
            //'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,          
            //'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
            ]);
        $footer = "<table name='footer' width=\"1000\">
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\"><u>SM</u></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\">9:00am to 9:00pm</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\">Friday Morning Closed</td>             
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"right\">Prop:      M.Sinha</td>
           </tr>
         </table>";
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
            'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            //'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            // any css to be embedded if required
            'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
             // set mPDF properties on the fly
            'options' => ['title' => 'Print Invoice'],
            //'options' => ['defaultfooterline' => 0,],
             // call mPDF methods on the fly
            'methods' => [
                //'SetHeader'=>['Amit Optical'], 
                'SetFooter'=>[$footer],
            ],
            'content' => $content,

        ]);

        }elseif($consoleid == 'CN'){
            $content = $this->renderPartial('_printinvoicegm', [
            'model' => $model,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel'  => $searchModel,

            'searchModel1' => $searchModel1,
            'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,

            // 'modelOffer' => $modelOffer,
            //'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,          
            //'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
            ]);
        $footer = "<table name='footer' width=\"1000\">
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\"><u>CN</u></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\">9:00am to 9:00pm</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\">Friday Morning Closed</td>             
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"right\">Prop:      M.Sinha</td>
           </tr>
         </table>";
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
            'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            //'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            // any css to be embedded if required
            'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
             // set mPDF properties on the fly
            'options' => ['title' => 'Print Invoice'],
            //'options' => ['defaultfooterline' => 0,],
             // call mPDF methods on the fly
            'methods' => [
                //'SetHeader'=>['Amit Optical'], 
                'SetFooter'=>[$footer],
            ],
            'content' => $content,

        ]);

        }


        return $pdf->render();
        //return $this->render('_printSalarystatement', ['s_period' => $s_period]);

    }
```

In this code, I'm getting error -

```
Undefined variable: consoleid
```

Please help.

**Update**

```
public function actionPrintinvoice($id) {

        $consoleid = 'My_console_id';
        $model = Bills::find()->where(['bills_ebillid' => $id])->one();
        $searchModel  = new BillsSearch();
        $searchModel->console = $consoleid;
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        //$data         = Sellsg::findOne($id);
        $searchModel1 = new ProductsalesSearch();
        $searchModel1->productsales_ebillid = $id;
        $dataProvider1 = $searchModel1->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        // $modelOffer  = Offers::find()->orderBy('of_id')->limit(1)->one();
        // $searchModel2 = new OffersSearch();       
        // $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        if($consoleid == 'GM1' || $consoleid == 'GM2'){
           $content = $this->renderPartial('_printinvoicegm', [
            'model' => $model,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel'  => $searchModel,

            'searchModel1' => $searchModel1,
            'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,

            // 'modelOffer' => $modelOffer,
            //'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,          
            //'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
            ]);
        $footer = "<table name='footer' width=\"1000\">
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\"><u>GM</u></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\">9:00am to 9:00pm</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\">Friday Morning Closed</td>             
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"right\">Prop:      M.Sinha</td>
           </tr>
         </table>";
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
            'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            //'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            // any css to be embedded if required
            'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
             // set mPDF properties on the fly
            'options' => ['title' => 'Print Invoice'],
            //'options' => ['defaultfooterline' => 0,],
             // call mPDF methods on the fly
            'methods' => [
                //'SetHeader'=>['Amit Optical'], 
                'SetFooter'=>[$footer],
            ],
            'content' => $content,

        ]);
        return $pdf->render(); 
        }elseif($consoleid == 'SM1' || $consoleid == 'SM2'){
            $content = $this->renderPartial('_printinvoicesm', [
            'model' => $model,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel'  => $searchModel,

            'searchModel1' => $searchModel1,
            'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,

            // 'modelOffer' => $modelOffer,
            //'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,          
            //'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
            ]);
        $footer = "<table name='footer' width=\"1000\">
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\"><u>SM</u></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\">9:00am to 9:00pm</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\">Friday Morning Closed</td>             
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"right\">Prop:      M.Sinha</td>
           </tr>
         </table>";
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
            'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            //'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            // any css to be embedded if required
            'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
             // set mPDF properties on the fly
            'options' => ['title' => 'Print Invoice'],
            //'options' => ['defaultfooterline' => 0,],
             // call mPDF methods on the fly
            'methods' => [
                //'SetHeader'=>['Amit Optical'], 
                'SetFooter'=>[$footer],
            ],
            'content' => $content,

        ]);
        return $pdf->render();
        }
        elseif($consoleid == 'CN'){
            $content = $this->renderPartial('_printinvoicecn', [
            'model' => $model,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel'  => $searchModel,

            'searchModel1' => $searchModel1,
            'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,

            // 'modelOffer' => $modelOffer,
            //'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,          
            //'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
            ]);
        $footer = "<table name='footer' width=\"1000\">
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\"><u>CN</u></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\">9:00am to 9:00pm</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\">Friday Morning Closed</td>             
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"right\">Prop:      M.Sinha</td>
           </tr>
         </table>";
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
            'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            //'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            // any css to be embedded if required
            'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
             // set mPDF properties on the fly
            'options' => ['title' => 'Print Invoice'],
            //'options' => ['defaultfooterline' => 0,],
             // call mPDF methods on the fly
            'methods' => [
                //'SetHeader'=>['Amit Optical'], 
                'SetFooter'=>[$footer],
            ],
            'content' => $content,

        ]);
        return $pdf->render();
        }
        //return $this->render('_printSalarystatement', ['s_period' => $s_period]);

    }
```

The index looks like below - 
[image]

I'm clicking on the print button to redirect to the respectiveprint pages.
The code of the action column is like below -

```
[
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{update} {print}',
            'buttons' => [
                'print' => function ($url, $model) {
                    return Html::a(
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span>',
                        ['/invoice/bills/printinvoice', 'id' => $model->bills_ebillid,'cons' => $model->console ], 
                        [
                            'title' => 'Print',
                            'data-pjax' => '0',
                        ]
                    );
                },
                ],
            ],
```

Now, the console is passing to the url but I'm unable to use it to redirect to different pages accordingly.
[image]

Comment: Because you never declared nor defined `$consoleid`. What is `$searchModel->console`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  are using a vars for assign that is not previosly defined with a proper content

```
public function actionPrintinvoice($id) {

    $model = Bills::find()->where(['bills_ebillid' => $id])->one();
    $searchModel  = new BillsSearch();
```

// this $consoleid is not defined   but you are try to accessing

```
    $searchModel->console = $consoleid;
```

You should define with a proper value before using

eg :

```
 $consoleid = 'My_console_id'
```

.
    public function actionPrintinvoice($id) {

```
$consoleid = 'My_console_id'   
$model = Bills::find()->where(['bills_ebillid' => $id])->one();
$searchModel  = new BillsSearch();
```

Update  comment too long

I have setted $consoleid = 'My_console_id' only to notify you that the reason for the error was dovita the fact that the variable was used before being assigned properly. : The fact remains that your code assigns that value to a parameter used for searching data to be selected .. I can not know what the correct values to be assigned to this parameter to make on a valid search (you should know) .. this may be the reason why you do not get nessu result and then get a blank page. So you should try to know what valid value your application must be assigned to $ consoleid because you can find the right data and then allow printing .. This also means that my answer has addressed the problem that you had reported ..

Looking at your code for printinvoce .. you pass as id  and console

```
 ['/invoice/bills/printinvoice', 'id' => $model->bills_ebillid,'cons' => $model->console ],
```

.. and you retrive  this info using

```
  $model = Bills::find()->where(['bills_ebillid' => $id])->one();
```

then you should change the signature of the function

```
public function actionPrintinvoice($id, $cons) {
 ......
```

and assign

```
$searchModel->console = $cons;
```

Comment: How should I define it?

Comment: I dont know the meaning of this var  .. for the definition you simply declare and assing a value  .. i have update the answer .. (you should eval to assign a proper content)

Comment: I've added  $consoleid = 'My_console_id' as you shown and by  $searchModel->console = $consoleid; I'm trying to pass console from the particular row to variable $consoleid. Please let me know if I'm doing it wrong or how to do that. I've added my current situation in the question under update. Now there's no error but when I'm clicking on the print button in actioncolumn I'm getting a blank page. I can see in the url that the id has been passed but no sign of consoleid. Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: I have update the answer with a note too long for comment .. take a look and if the code run   .. . thiis means that my answer has resolved  the problem that you had reported ..

Comment: The variable $consoleid is defined by now. But how to get value of  field 'console' of the particular row that has been selected and pass it to variable $consoleid - this piece of question is remaining.

Comment: @Tanmay  ..If not you know how should I know .. if you know it in the form that calls this function you pass it into the function call or since you have $ id could be that $ consoleid is in some way obtainable by this value .. .. I I can help you with the errors in the code .. but what is the application you use and what are the variables you must know

Comment: I'm added some more info in the question. Please have a look.